# How to change text direction to 45 degrees in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, word-processing

I want to add a table with the long description header but I can't find how to change text direct other than 90 degrees (Vertical or Horizontal). Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you just use a simple text box for the text you want to rotate?

Comment: I can try. This table has about 30 columns. The prefer way is to make it just as a regular table.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this in Word tables, but if you insert an Excel spreadsheet into a Word document (Insert tab > Tables > Excel Spreadsheet) you can then type in your heading in a cell. Then, right click the CELL and select "Format Cells...". Then, goto the Alignment tab and specify the text angle on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate Word Art text freely. It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it works. Just click the green dot and rotate away.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate words at a 45 degree angle if they are in a text box. The only problem I've had is keeping the text box in place once I've put it where I want it.

Comment: For that part you could probably group the elements